# Centos 7.6 yum install python36 vs python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am running a server with Centos 7.6 and we have python36 installed

```
 yum list installed | grep python36
 python36u.x86_64                     3.6.8-1.el7.ius                   @ius
 python36u-libs.x86_64                3.6.8-1.el7.ius                   @ius
 python36u-pip.noarch                 9.0.1-1.ius.el7                   @ius
 python36u-setuptools.noarch          39.0.1-1.ius.el7                  @ius
```

however, I also need python36-devel, but when I try to yum install it, it tells me that python3 has obsoleted python36 and it wants to install that.  How will that impact any current applications that rely on python36?

```
 yum install python36-devel
 ...
 Package python36-devel is obsoleted by python3-devel, trying to install python3-devel-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 instead
 ...
 Installing:
 python3-devel                         x86_64                3.6.8-10.el7                  
 Installing for dependencies:
  dwz                                   x86_64                0.11-3.el7                                 
  libtirpc                              x86_64                0.2.4-0.16.el7       
  perl-srpm-macros                      noarch                1-8.el7                               
  python-rpm-macros                     noarch                3-32.el7                          
  python-srpm-macros                    noarch                3-32.el7                              
  python3                               x86_64                3.6.8-10.el7                         
  python3-libs                          x86_64                3.6.8-10.el7                          
  python3-pip                           noarch                9.0.3-5.el7                           
  python3-rpm-generators                noarch                6-2.el7                               
  python3-rpm-macros                    noarch                3-32.el7                              
  python3-setuptools                    noarch                39.2.0-10.el7
```

It will also replace python36 with python3.  I am wondering how will that impact any current applications that rely on python36?

Comment: This was so long ago, now I can't remember if I just installed python3-dev or just left it as is and forgot about the whole thing...